# Logstash: configuring aggregate + elapsed filters

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have these logs:

```
"03.08.2020 10:56:38","Event LClick","Type Menu","t=0","beg"
"03.08.2020 10:56:38","Event LClick","Type Menu","Detail SomeDetail","t=109","end"
"03.08.2020 10:56:40","Event LClick","t=1981","beg"
"03.08.2020 10:56:40","Event LClick","t=2090","end"
"03.08.2020 10:56:41","Event LClick","Type ToolBar","t=3026","beg"
"03.08.2020 10:56:43","Event LClick","Type ToolBar","Detail User_Desktop","t=4477","end"
"03.08.2020 10:56:44","Event FormActivate","Name Form_Name:IsaA","t=5444"
"03.08.2020 10:56:51","Event LClick","t=12543","beg"
"03.08.2020 10:56:51","Event LClick","t=12605","end"
"03.08.2020 10:56:52","Event LClick","Form ","Type Label","Name Application.for.training","t=13853","beg"
"03.08.2020 10:57:54","Event LClick","Form Application.for.training","Type Label","Name Application.for.training","t=75442","end"
"03.08.2020 10:57:54","Event FormActivate","Name List.form","t=75785"
"03.08.2020 10:58:04","Event Wheel","Form List.form","Type FormTable","Name Список","t=85769","beg"
"03.08.2020 10:58:04","Event Wheel","Form List.form","Type FormTable","Name Список","t=85769","end"
"03.08.2020 10:58:04","Event Wheel","Form List.form","Type FormTable","Name Список","t=85847","beg"
"03.08.2020 10:58:04","Event Wheel","Form List.form","Type FormTable","Name Список","t=85847","end"
"03.08.2020 10:58:04","Event Wheel","Form List.form","Type FormTable","Name Список","t=85879","beg"
"03.08.2020 10:58:04","Event Wheel","Form List.form","Type FormTable","Name Список","t=85879","end"
"03.08.2020 10:58:04","Event Wheel","Form List.form","Type FormTable","Name Список","t=85925","beg"
"03.08.2020 10:58:04","Event Wheel","Form List.form","Type FormTable","Name Список","t=85925","end"
"03.08.2020 10:58:08","Event LClick","Form List.form","Type FormTable","Name Список","t=89373","beg"
"03.08.2020 10:58:08","Event LClick","Form List.form","Type FormTable","Name Список","Detail Data","t=89451","end"
"03.08.2020 10:58:15","Event LClick","Form List.form","Type FormTable","Name Список","t=96580","beg"
"03.08.2020 10:58:15","Event LClick","Form List.form","Type FormTable","Name Список","Detail Data","t=96643","end"
"03.08.2020 10:58:15","Event LBtnDbl","Form List.form","Type FormTable","Name Список","t=96752","beg"
"03.08.2020 10:59:22","Event FormActivate","Name Another.Form","t=164004"
"03.08.2020 10:59:22","Event LBtnDbl","Form Another.Form","Type FormTable","Name Список","Detail Data","t=164004","end"
"03.08.2020 10:59:25","Event LClick","Form Another.Form","Type ToolBar","Name КоманднаяПанельПереченьРеквизитов","t=167171","beg"
"03.08.2020 10:59:26","Event LClick","Form Another.Form","Type ToolBar","Name КоманднаяПанельПереченьРеквизитов","Detail Заполнить","t=167249","end"
...
```

My logstash config:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => '5044'
    }
}
 filter {
    grok {
        patterns_dir => ['./patterns']
        match => { 'message' => '%{TIME:timestamp}(","Event\s)(?<Event>([^"]+))(","Form\s)?(?<Form>([^"]+))?(","ParentType\s)?(?<parent_type>([^"]+))?(","ParentName\s)?(?<parent_name>([^"]+))?(","Type\s)?(?<type>([^"]+))?(","Name\s)?(?<Name_of_form>([^"]+))?(","Detail\s)?(?<Detail>([^"]+))?(","t=)?(?<t>([\d]+))?(",")?(?<Status>(end|beg))?' }
        add_tag => [ '%{Status}' ]
    }
    dissect {
        mapping => {
            '[log][file][path]' => 'C:\Program Files\Filebeat\logs\%{somethingtoo}\%{something}\%{user}\%{filename}.txt'
        }
    }
    date {
        match => [ 'timestamp', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss' ]
    }
    elapsed {
        unique_id_field => 'Event'
        start_tag => 'beg'
        end_tag => 'end'
        new_event_on_match => false
    }

    if 'elapsed' in [tags] {
        aggregate {
            task_id => '%{Event}'
            code => 'map["duration"] = [(event.get("elapsed_time")*1000).to_i]'
            map_action => 'create'
        }
    }
    mutate {
        remove_field => ['timestamp', 'ecs', 'log', 'tags', 'message', '@version', 'something', 'somethingtoo', 'filename', 'input', 'host', 'agent', 't', 'parent_type', 'parent_name', 'type']
        rename => {'elapsed_time' => 'Event_duration'}
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ['localhost:9200']
        index => 'test'
    }
}
```

**Question**: now I calculate the time difference between the lines using beg (the beginning of an action) and end (the end of an action). But that doesn't make much sense because it's almost always 0 seconds. How would I implement it like this: when a form field appears in the line (if 'Form' in message), consider the difference between the first appearance of a certain form and the last appearance. How can I implement this if it is not clear what to bind the end_tag to.

For the logs above, I should get the following:

1. Some form is activated (Event FormActivate), in a separate field form name (Name Name_of_form). Then the actions of this form follow (the time of which must be counted) and then the activation of the new form and so on until the end of the file.
2. As long as the form is the same. Move on.
3. The last appearance of this form in a row
4. Elapsed_time: "08/03/2020 10:58:15" - "08/03/2020 10:58:04" = 11 seconds

I would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: So `beg` and `end` are not valid markers for your events. You should match on the form name instead and use the [third aggregate strategy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate-example3) and create events based on a timeout.

Comment: @Val It's a good idea, but how do I use this with the elapsed filter? This filter must have an end_tag specified to track the time.

Comment: In my opinion, you don't need the `elapsed` filter and can simply have your code in the `timeout_code` parameter of the `aggregate` filter. You can also probably use the [fifth strategy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate-example5) of the `aggregate` filter

Comment: @Val I honestly can't figure out how to calculate the time difference using only the aggregate filter. I cannot find even a similar example.